# SSRS Matrix Reports (Calculated Fields)

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Please see below matrix report before and after I run.

[image]

How can I find percentage of below marked fields, for example: 2/6=0.3 (%33)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an expression in each of your `Gender Percentage` Female/Male columns to get the count of each gender in that group compared to the number of members in the group:

**Male**

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Gender.Value = "M", 1, 0)) / Count(Fields!Members.Value)
```

**Female**

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Gender.Value = "F", 1, 0)) / Count(Fields!Members.Value)
```

This is getting the total male or female members in the scope then getting the percentage of the overall member count.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I do the same thing for "PAs" column.

Comment: For exmp: 1/3=0.33 (%33) Female(PAs)/Total(PAs)=?

Comment: You can probably use something like `=Sum(IIf(Fields!Gender.Value = "F", Fields!PAs.Value, Nothing)) / Sum(Fields!PAs.Value)`. If you need more information it would be best if you ask a new question.

Comment: Did you get your `Gender Percentage` expression working?